# Why is my nav search bar shortened when the code is not on the website?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, searchbar

So I have this code that I am using from online, When i go to use it, I get a short Search bar, but when its from this website http://www.bootply.com/103530#. The search bar is the full length. I have tried it with bootstrap css and no css at all, but they still do not match the website, can anyone help me out?

**Edit**: JSFiddle example with Bootstrap 3.x http://jsfiddle.net/hkqLtdvw/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapsible">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-collapsible">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="navbar-form navbar-right btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 2</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 3</button>
      </div>

      <form class="navbar-form">
        <div class="form-group" style="display:inline;">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>

    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: There must be a discrepancy between your CSS and the CSS being used on that page.

Comment: Do you have still included the bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js

Comment: I have tried it with no css, and basic bootstrap css. But the website I get it from does not use/provide CSS, So I am wondering why it is that why online and not on my end.

Comment: We can't very well help without access to the alternative scenario.

Comment: @isherwood I provided the basic css and js that I used, and this creates what I have the problem with, short search bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

and this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

and you have your answer.

Specifically, the styles for `.input-group` change from `display: table` to `display: inline-table`.

Comment: Is there an easier way to read them then to just look at the link? It is a lot of block. Also would there be a way to use it with 3.3 bootstrap? If I am using other elements that 3.3 uses? Instead of you doing the work for me, how can i view these in a user friendly way in order to make the additional changes in the style sheet. I ask because now the "search button" has stopped working.

Comment: Are you asking how to view the source of a page? I thought that was common knowledge. Right-click, 'view source'. In the case of your markup, it's right there, of course. In the case of your Bootply, it's shown in the sidebar.

Comment: All Bootstrap 3 versions are fairly interchangeable (with minor adjustments). I wouldn't hesitate to upgrade your project if you're the only (or primary) developer.

Comment: Or maybe you're asking how to inspect styles. I use Chrome's document inspector: right-click, 'inspect'.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong version of bootstrap, change to `3.0.0` and it will fix your problem.

See fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/xtat0oa6/

this is the CDN https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css

Answer (score -1):

try this in css

```
 .input-group {width: 200px;}
```

Comment: Did not change the search bar.

Comment: @Renuz please check this link http://www.bootply.com/5ij0mcuqN6